Questions with bounties should be way more visible
I started a bounty a few days ago (Fill form fields in Colab notebook from URL query parameters) and for the life of me I can not find the bounty list. And I've been around SO for a while.
Shouldn't these questions be given more visibility in the front page or in a link clearly noticeable? This is a 5 year old question, if it remains mostly hidden despite having a large bounty, what's the point?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-colaboratory?tab=Bounties

You can find a tab with all the bountied questions at the top of the question list: https://i.sstatic.net/pFr9YQfg.png . Your question also got bumped to the top of the active question tab.

Thank you both but my point is that all bountied questions should be more visible. From the homepage I have to click the menu on the top left, then Questions, then Bountied. I think this is too much

Bountied questions get their own entire section of the site and it's explicitly highlighted that there are questions with bounties on the questions page. That's a lot of prominence already than that "average" question.

Am I recalling correctly that it used to be linked from the logged-in homepage?  Or was it only ever from /questions?

As the old home page had the Active, Bountied, Hot, Week, Month, options (like on other sites that that don't have to suffer the new home page yet (such as [dba.se], [ubuntu.se], [su], etc)), they were, @RyanM , however, answerers probably more often filtered to the questions the wanted to answer on the questions page. It is, however, another example of why the new home page is so bad.

A lack of attention to your question is probably the tag. If I see voting and answering activity under google-colaboratory, it's like a barren wasteland. No bounty is going to change that state of being.

Bounties are quite visible if one's looking for questions to answer.
As you very probably know, users looking for questions to answer use tags to filter subjects where they have expertise. Someone looking for questions about google-colaboratory to answer, will find it quickly enough:

Someone who's not interested in that tag, or who's not even searching for questions to answer; will not likely be able to post an answer in any case; so promoting the bounty to them would be redundant at best.
There are currently 87 bountied questions on the site, and the bounties remain active for a whole week. I don't think that further promoting these to the front-page or something like that is a good idea.

I agree with everything said here, and I don't think bounties need more visibility. But out of curiosity, I wonder if bounties are quite as "effective" as they used to be. Wandering off to SEDE.
